Unable To Send Solana / Swap Solana With Any Coin . My Wallet Is Bricked/Freezed/Compromised
My wallet has been compromised. Like I can't make any transaction with it and it is just useless. I have 1000$ in that wallet
Is there any way to recover it??
Like any way to recover
I don't have ownership because someone else changed it idk how ? But I own the wallet
I have tried to send transaction on every platform but it fails and I can't do anything
